# Can I see in firebug profiler funcitons list in order those call?

Tags: javascript, profiling, firebug

Can I see in firebug profiler funcitons list in order those call? 
Do you may be know another tools for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [JavaScript Deobfuscator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345) plugin. It shows all javascript runed on the webpage